# pry-byebugがインストールされてるか自動判別して常に`c`などの一文字aliasを使わない方法

Tags: ruby, pry

`pry-byebug`が有効な状態で`c`などを使うと以下の様なエラーになる問題があります。

```
c = 3
Error: Cannot find local context. Did you use `binding.pry`?
```

この対処に

```
Pry::Commands.delete 'c'
Pry::Commands.delete 'n'
Pry::Commands.delete 's'
```

と `~/.pryrc`に書いた場合、`Gemfile`の設定などで`pry-byebug`が入ってないと今度は起動時に以下の様なエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Error loading /Users/ironsand/Dropbox/rc/.pryrc: Cannot find a command: 'c'!
/Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/command_set.rb:191:in `find_command_by_match_or_listing'
```

どちらの環境でもエラーを出さずに`c`,`n`,`s`のaliasのコマンドを無効化するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pry-byebug`が入っていないために`Cannot find a command: 'c'!`が出ると勘違いしてしまっていたのですが @todashuta さんの回答により `defined?(PryByebug)` が `"constant"`を返し存在することから、`pry-byebug`が入っていないのではなく alias が行われていないだけだということがわかりました。

具体的には `3.0` より前の`pry-byebug`では標準で実装されていた一文字 alias が削除されていたためこのエラーがでていたようです。

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pry-byebug/3.1.0

・`pry-byebug`がインストールされていない
・`3.0`より前のバージョンがインストールされている
・`3.0`移行のバージョンが入ってる

全ての状態に対応するために以下の設定を`~/.pryrc`に行いました。
`Pry::Commands.delete 'c'`がエラーを出さないためにあえて一度 alias を定義させています。

```
if defined?(PryByebug)
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'f', 'finish'
  Pry::Commands.delete 'c'
  Pry::Commands.delete 's'
  Pry::Commands.delete 'n'
  Pry::Commands.delete 'f'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if defined?(PryByebug)
  Pry::Commands.delete 'c'
  Pry::Commands.delete 'n'
  Pry::Commands.delete 's'
end
```

これでどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。このコードでも`Cannot find a command: 'c'!`が出てしまったのですが、おかげで原因が特定出来ました。